React native calendar - timeline - disable given hours
Is there any supported functionality to get parts of the timeline strike trough (disabled), similar to the screenshot below?

I saw in the documentation that there are start and end which can do something similar to that, I decided to ask non the less.
Any help will be apriciated


have you tried using "unavailableHours" prop for the timelineProps? i think you can use it and set the start and end time for the unavailability and color of the background for it in the timeline.

yep, this is it, thank you!
